# How to avoid empty automatic option in an angularjs select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<form ng-show="editingUser" class="form-inline editingUser" role="form" name="gebruikerdetailform" novalidate>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userDetail.name" placeholder="Naam" ng-required="true"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userDetail.surname" placeholder="Surname"/>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="userDetail.role">
    <option ng-selected="userDetail.role === 'user' || userDetail.role === ''" >user</option>
    <option ng-selected="userDetail.role === 'admin'">admin</option>
</select>
</form>
```

in this code, automatically the empty option `<option value="? string: ?"></option>` is created by angularjs. i know it happens when a value referenced by **ng-model** doesn't exist in a the **ng-options**.
but this is not the case, and i don't understand how to avoid this behavior, and where does it come from.
any ideas?

Comment: How to write a good title - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: $scope.userDetail.role = 'user' #default value

Comment: thanks, adding always a value to the userDetail.role solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem concerns the initialization of the *ng-model*, you can use the directive `ng-init`, as follows:

```
<form ng-show="editingUser" class="form-inline editingUser" role="form" name="gebruikerdetailform" novalidate>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userDetail.name" placeholder="Naam" ng-required="true"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userDetail.surname" placeholder="Surname"/>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="userDetail.role" ng-init="user">
    <option ng-selected="userDetail.role === 'user' || userDetail.role === ''" >user</option>
    <option ng-selected="userDetail.role === 'admin'">admin</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Look at the usage of the `ng-init` directive in the select definition.

For more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Cheers